# Should I import these large arrays or data as .js, JSON, hardcoded into JSX or..?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using `NextJS/React`, and a component library called Semantic UI for React.

I want to make use of the `Dropdown` component which has built-in search features. Here is an example from https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown/#types-search-selection

```
const countryOptions = [
  { key: 'af', value: 'af', flag: 'af', text: 'Afghanistan' },
  { key: 'ax', value: 'ax', flag: 'ax', text: 'Aland Islands' },
  { key: 'al', value: 'al', flag: 'al', text: 'Albania' },
  { key: 'dz', value: 'dz', flag: 'dz', text: 'Algeria' },
  { key: 'as', value: 'as', flag: 'as', text: 'American Samoa' },
  { key: 'ad', value: 'ad', flag: 'ad', text: 'Andorra' },
  { key: 'ao', value: 'ao', flag: 'ao', text: 'Angola' },
  { key: 'ai', value: 'ai', flag: 'ai', text: 'Anguilla' },
  { key: 'ag', value: 'ag', flag: 'ag', text: 'Antigua' },
  { key: 'ar', value: 'ar', flag: 'ar', text: 'Argentina' },
  { key: 'am', value: 'am', flag: 'am', text: 'Armenia' },
  { key: 'aw', value: 'aw', flag: 'aw', text: 'Aruba' },
  { key: 'au', value: 'au', flag: 'au', text: 'Australia' },
  { key: 'at', value: 'at', flag: 'at', text: 'Austria' },
  { key: 'az', value: 'az', flag: 'az', text: 'Azerbaijan' },
  { key: 'bs', value: 'bs', flag: 'bs', text: 'Bahamas' },
  { key: 'bh', value: 'bh', flag: 'bh', text: 'Bahrain' },
  { key: 'bd', value: 'bd', flag: 'bd', text: 'Bangladesh' },
  { key: 'bb', value: 'bb', flag: 'bb', text: 'Barbados' },
  { key: 'by', value: 'by', flag: 'by', text: 'Belarus' },
  { key: 'be', value: 'be', flag: 'be', text: 'Belgium' },
  { key: 'bz', value: 'bz', flag: 'bz', text: 'Belize' },
  { key: 'bj', value: 'bj', flag: 'bj', text: 'Benin' },
]

const DropdownExampleSearchSelection = () => (
  <Dropdown
    placeholder='Select Country'
    fluid
    search
    selection
    options={countryOptions}
  />
)
```

**My issue**
I have around 4-5 different dropdowns, all in total having around 3000-4000 items. This means that this is a lot of elements on the DOM lol.

Assuming I have no other alternative than to do it this way: what would be the fastest/most compressed way of importing/getting the data needed for the dropdowns in my project?

I have a couple of ideas and really want to figure out what's the most 'correct' and 'efficient' way of handling this large amount of data both for the browser and server.

Should I store this data as JSON files, and import them at build time using NextJS's Static-Site Generation? Should I store these arrays as `.JS` files and import them into the components that use them? Or should I instead store them like in the example above: as a `const` variable inside the `.js` file, either outside or inside the component? (i am worried reacts re-rendering might cause unwanted reloads of these large amounts of data if I store it as JS variables).

Or should I just hardcode it inside the JSX and call it a day?

Beginner dev and not sure what the correct approach is for this

Comment: You can use library like [react-window](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-window), which only renders elements as you scroll, not the whole list.

Comment: @MadhanS that's not the fix to the problem the OP is trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can store it in a js file. Besides, I think since the key, value, and flag are the same value, it's not required to store them in tree property.

```
const DropdownExampleSearchSelection = () => (
  const options = useMemo(() => 
    countryOptions.map(({value, text})=> 
      ({ key: value, value, flag: value, text})
  ,[countryOptions])

  return <Dropdown
    placeholder='Select Country'
    fluid
    search
    selection
    options={options}
  />
)
```

Comment: Hi yes I was recently exploring the useMemo hook. So my question is: the usememo is storing this javascript array permanently in memory somewhere until the countryOptions dependency changes? meaning that on every rerender the options array is stored somewhere? It confuses me  because the Dropdown component would be rerendered on stsate change, but the options for it is not thanks to useMemo.. but does that mean its still on the DOM or does react rerender all the dropdown options as dom elemtns anyway?

Comment: React will render the options of virtual DOM instead of the actual DOM unless the virtual dom is changed. The reason to use useMemo is to prevent running the function inside the useMemo every time.